# Delete the autorun key from the command processor in the registry

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-registry, autorun

Every time I tried to run `cmd` recently it would just pop-up and close immediately, and only Powershell worked on my PC.

I found a solution that asked me to navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` and delete the `Autorun` key. I did it and all worked correctly (`cmd` opened as normal).

When I restarted my PC and logged in, there was a blank screen with a `cmd` window open. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you unable to login now or is it a stupid window you need to close to proceed?  If you can get into windows, use the [autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) application and identify what is running at startup.  You shouldn't NEED the Autorun key.

Comment: No, if I close the cmd, there is just a black screen. Typing "explorer" on the cmd solves the problem, but I have to do it everytime I start the computer, so is a little annoying, nothing more

Comment: what does autoruns show you that is running at startup?  And yes.. totally annoying Señor.